# Timesheet field addition and update in account analytic line

Tags: odoo, openerp-7

I have added two fields in timesheet detail, i want to add the values of these two fields in **account_analytic_line** table, how can i do it?

Here is .py file

```
from osv import osv, fields

class hr_analytic_timesheet(osv.osv):
    _inherit = "hr.analytic.timesheet"
    _columns = {
           'start_at1':fields.char('Start at', size=170),
               'end_at1':fields.char('End at', size=170),
                }          
hr_analytic_timesheet()
```

And here is view.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
    <data>
        <record model="ir.ui.view" id="hr_timesheet_inherit">
            <field name="name">hr.timesheet.sheet.form</field>
            <field name="model">hr_timesheet_sheet.sheet</field>
            <field name="type">form</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="hr_timesheet_sheet.hr_timesheet_sheet_form" />
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <xpath expr="//field[@name='unit_amount']" position="after">
                    <field name="start_at1" />
                    <field name="end_at1" />
                </xpath>

            </field>
        </record>
    </data>
</openerp>
```

Comment: have you get any error or no output ?

Comment: no error, values gets updated in hr.analytic.timesheet, i want to add the value in account_analytic_line

Answer (score 2):

When you look into the technical memento (https://www.openerp.com/files/memento/) on page 2, you will see the 2 types of inheritance in OpenERP.

hr.analytic.timesheet model is using the second one (Delegation or Decorating) and so your fields wont go into the account_analytic_line table, but into the hr_analytic_timesheet table.

if you really want to have this fields in account_analytic_line table just inherit from analytic.account.line and extend that class instead. you can now use the new fields in hr.analytic.timesheet too, so your view with id "hr_timesheet_inherit" should fit anyways (nothing to change here).

hope this will help.

Comment: thanks Czoellner I have tranfer my field in the model of account_analytic_line and now i can add the field in both view the account_analytic_line and in the ht_anlaytic_timesheet.